# Change Ag-Grid infinite scroll block size?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Is there a way to change the block size when the row model used is "infinite" and a datasource is set?

I.e. when the datasource's `getRows()` is called, is there a way to set `startRow` and/or `endRow`? Default behaviour is to fetch 100 rows at a time which results in blank rows for me, since I only have about ~12 new data rows coming in at a time with infinite scroll. So, when `getRows()` is triggered, it'll try to fetch rows 100 to 200 (as an example) when there are only 45 data points in the first place. To compensate it adds a bunch of blank rows.

I've tried the following two additional grid options without success:

```
cacheOverflowSize: 2
infiniteInitialRowCount: 32
```

Fetching 100 rows at a time instead of 12 solves the issue, but I'd reeeeeally rather not do this (due to some design constraints of the product I'm working on).

Comment: Try to use `cacheBlockSize` this defines under infinite how fetched request for data should be chunked - for example setting `cacheBlockSize` to 12 defines that data will be fetched in blocks of 12 rows at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoutout to @kamil-kubicki for their comment. `cacheBlockSize` was indeed what I was looking for. It didn't solve my whole problem though, so I'll outline my complete solution below.

I had ag-grid's row height set to the default `25px` max. That meant that on load, when it was populating the initial data, it was coming close to rendering my entire initial data set of 32 items. On scroll, `getRows()` would then look for rows outside of the total data collection's bounds, so it added blank rows.

I changed how many data results are loaded on each scroll to 50. This is relatively large but it works and is performant for now, so I think I'll keep it.

**For those with a similar problem:**

1. Use `cacheBlockSize` in `gridOptions`
2. Make sure that your ag-grid isn't rendering anything close to your full initial data collection (e.g. if your collection is 32 items, don't render anything above like 16 items - control this by changing the height of your rows and the size of your grid)
3. Change how many data items are loaded in to your collection on scroll to a larger number; something that can populate data faster than the user can scroll. For me it was 50. For you it might be more, or less.